# How to lazy load for a div section with ajax or java

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a div section that includes hundreds of tables from my database.

The problem I am having is when the page loads it is really slow. So you wait a long time for it to load.

Can anyone assist me in showing how to load just the visible area in my `div.`

**Note : I can't use Boostrap DataTable because my row does not contain a head and body like normal tables do.**

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a neat solution. You can target specific elements via a class. So all you need to do is add the class appear to whatever you want to lazyload.

Appearlazy uses appear.js to lazy load images or divs that have an "appear" class. It works by switching a data-src attribute into the src as an image is identified as viewable.

http://creativelive.github.io/appear/examples/lazy/

There are however quite a few different solutions for lazy loading.

See available JS scripts here - https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/lazyload/

I think the most widely used one though is lazyload.js - https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/

**Example**

You can use this script for lazy loading a div.
https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any

Add a class called my-lazyload (or whatever) to the div you want to lazyload.

**HTML**

```
<div id="my-lazyload">
  <!--
    <p>Your content here</p>
  -->
</div>
```

In your jQuery code you select the class and call the lazyload function.
**JavaScript**

```
$`('#my-lazyload').lazyload(options);`
```

Hope it will help. You can view the explanation in more detail on the page

You will need to link to jQuery and Lazyload js files

```
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lazyload-any.js"></script>
```

You will just link to your own CSS. No special CSS required for lazyload.

Comment: yes that can be somethgin that I want but I couldnt find a clear example :S

Comment: Thankx for helps.. and for header and footer css and scrip documnts link can you share?

Comment: You will need to download both scripts or link to them via their own repos. Then you will link to them like you do normal JS files. See updated example. If you visit the link there is a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for all your helps..I am trying to do it.. I will update if I can do i.. My div section have if loops etc so I hope I will be able to do that..